# Show SweetAlert2 popup upon login

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert2

I'm building a simple admin panel and want a SweetAlert2 popup to be displayed each time a user logs in.

My users get redirected to index.php upon login successfully and I want that when the user loaded in index.php the popup will display.

How do I do it? :)

Comment: Just write some JavaScript which loads your alert immediately - it will run when the page loads. Then you can write something maybe to the session which says not to load that script in future for the rest of the session. It's unclear where you're stuck exactly. Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code on your page

```
if ($m == 'success') { echo '
Swal.fire({
  position: "bottom-end",
  type: "success",
  title: "'.$message.'",
  showConfirmButton: false,
  timer: 1500,
  confirmButtonClass: "btn btn-primary",
  buttonsStyling: false,
})
'; }
```